# Can I assign a value to a var from another which I don't know if exist in one row?

Tags: php, variables, if-statement, asp-classic, isset

I'm looking for a better and easy way to do this. I remember I saw a shorthand somewhere.

```
if (isset($user['passport'])) $passport=$user['passport'];
```

> **Edited to let you know what I mean**

**Classic ASP:**

```
user=request.form("user")
response.write user
```

**ASP** doesn't care if user exists, so **prints nothing**

**The same in PHP**

```
$user=$_POST['user'];
echo $user;
```

**PHP prints Notice: Undefined variable**

Comment: like this??? `$passport = (isset($user['passport']) ? $user['passport'] : '');`

Comment: @devpro Post it as answer

Comment: @LPK: alright, yes posted as an answer.. :)

Comment: check you edit, u need to use isset() otherwise u will get the undefined notice  in php

Comment: I know, that's why I'm asking a fastest way

Comment: Chose the best answer and mark as accepted

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need shorthand condition than you can use `ternary operator` as:

```
$passport = (isset($user['passport']) ? $user['passport'] : '');
```

Comment: I like your answer, this works also without parenthesis but anyway in all the answer I've to repeat **$user['passport']**

Answer (score 2):

You can use PHP ternary operator for this purpose

Link to learn about ternary operator http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Sample php code

```
<?php
// Example usage for: Ternary Operator
$passport = (isset($user['passport'])) ? $user['passport'] : '';

// The above is identical to this if/else statement
if (isset($user['passport'])) {
    $passport = $user['passport'];
} else {
    $passport = '';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try this :**

```
$passport = ($user['passport'])?: '';
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: passport :(

Comment: error_reporting(E_ALL);
$user = array(); AND $user = array('passport'=>'passport');
$passport = ($user['passport'])?: '';
echo $passport;

Comment: I have added both the test case above your quote, both working fine for me

Comment: what if $user doesn't contains passport??

Comment: in that case you can add like this @$user['passport']

Answer (score 0):

Classic ASP '*may not care*', but don't be fooled by apparently none existent values.  Sometimes they do contain something, e.g. `Nothing`.  This all depends, of course, on the original source of the value.

A quick and dirty method that I tend to use to force variants of a particular type is to append an empty string to the beginning, e.g.:

```vbs
user = "" & Request.Form("user")
'As a numeric example from a different source...
count = CInt("0" & rs("record_count"))
```

For PHP you could consider:

```php
$passport = "" . $user[passport];
```

(I don't know a great deal about PHP, unfortunately.)

Answer (score -1):

```
$passport=$user['passport']?$user['passport']:"Value if not set";
```

Comment: even if $user['passport'] is not bool, it would work, please try.

Comment: You are right. But why? Because $user['passport'] isn't null?

Comment: Nope, even if its null it would work, by default it consider it like isset.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: passport

Comment: @Vixed - Which php version you are using?